# Total free web application (Scripts Store, DB store)

Tags: android, javascript, database, mysql, shell-scripting

I want to develop my own personal application working online using Web browser.

I need to find the Online Servers :

```
Where I can store my DB (MySQL, MariaDB) totally free?

Where I can to store my Scripts (PHP, Java), HTML, JQuery, etc..
```

I want to run my application from Android Mobile...

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Answer (score 0):

Its customary to run everything on your own environment while developing. That said, [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/products/technologies) does run the technologies you mentioned and they have a free plan.